# Error: Method not found: 'setState'. Flutter SetState Method Problem

Tags: flutter, setstate

```
 import 'dart:async';   
 import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';   
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';   
 import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';    

 class ListViewScreen extends StatefulWidget{    

 @override
_ListViewScreenState createState() => _ListViewScreenState();
 }

class _ListViewScreenState extends State<ListViewScreen> {
final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>  _key = GlobalKey();

 List<String> _items = [
  'Coffee',
  'Energy Drink',
  'Monster',
  'Latte',
];

@override   
Widget build(BuildContext context)  {    
  return MaterialApp(    
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,    
  home: Scaffold(      
    appBar: AppBar(     
      title: Text('Animated List'),   
    ),    
    body: AnimatedList(    
      key: _key,      
      initialItemCount: _items.length,     
      itemBuilder: (context,index,animation){    
        return _buildItem(_items[index],animation,index);    
      },   
    ),    
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(    
        onPressed : (){    
          _addItem();    
          CustomIndicator.StartTimer();    
        }    
    ),   
  ),    
);    
}   

Widget _buildItem(String item, Animation animation, int index){     
return SizeTransition(     
  sizeFactor: animation,      
  child: Card(     
    elevation: 2,     
    child: ListTile(    
      title: Text(     
        item,    
        style: TextStyle(      
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600     
        ),     
      ),      
      subtitle: Text('lorem ipsum dolor...'),    
      leading: CircularPercentIndicator(     
        radius: 30,     
        lineWidth: 2.0,    
        animation: true,    
        animateFromLastPercent: true,    
        percent:0,      
        progressColor: Colors.amber,     
      ),    
      trailing: IconButton(     
        icon: Icon(Icons.close,color: Colors.amberAccent,),    
        onPressed: (){    
          _removeItem(index);    

        },    
      ),    
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

```
  void _removeItem (int i){     
 String removedItem = _items.removeAt(i);             
 AnimatedListRemovedItemBuilder builder = (context,animation){    
     return _buildItem(removedItem, animation, i);    
    };   
 _key.currentState.removeItem(i, builder);    
}      

void _addItem() {     
  int i = _items.length>0  ? _items.length : 0;    
  _items.insert(i, 'Item ${_items.length+1}');    
  _key.currentState.insertItem(i);
```

}
}

```
 class CustomIndicator extends State<ListViewScreen> {    

static double _percent = 0;    
static int TimeInMinut = 1;   
 int TimeInSec = TimeInMinut * 60;    
static Timer timer;    

static StartTimer() {    
  TimeInMinut = 1;   
  int Time = TimeInMinut * 60;     
double SecPercent = (Time / 100);     
timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {    
  setState(() {    
    if (Time > 0) {    
      Time--;     
      if (Time % 60 == 0) {     
        TimeInMinut--;     
      }     
      if (Time % SecPercent == 0) {     
        if (_percent < 1) {     
          _percent += 0.01;     
        } else {    
          _percent = 1;     
        }   
      }    
    } else {         
      _percent = 0;    
      TimeInMinut = 25;    
      timer.cancel();    
    }
  }
  );
}
);
```

}

```
     static double getPercent() {    
      double wpercent =.0;    
      wpercent = _percent;    

    return wpercent;    
}

 @override    
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    // TODO: implement build    
   throw UnimplementedError();    
}
```

}
I am just a beginner in Flutter Programming and this is one of the pages of the app I am making.
I know the code is poorly built but I only need it to work...
Error: Method not found: 'setState'. this is the error message.
What I am trying to do here is put a CircularPercentIndicator in the leading part of the ListTile card.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is an instance level method. You cannot call an instance level method from a `static` method. Maybe remove the `static` from your method and variables? I don't know your plan or requirement is that you are having it, so I cannot really tell you a solution, but you cannot have both, a `static` method and calling `setState` in it will not work.